# How to rename files with a specific pattern in R?

Tags: r, rename, filenames

There are some [.fcs](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cyto.a.20825/abstract;jsessionid=249FEAB8AE92A9DC8229F4F8BB43104F.d03t02) files in a *data.000X* format (where X = 1, 2, 3...) in a directory.

I want to rename every *n* file to the following format: *exp.fcs* (where *exp* is a text from a vector) if the file to be renamed is an *.fcs* file.

*in other words*: I want to rename files to exp.txt, where *exp* is a text and not a consecutive letter(s) i.e. F, cA, K, etc.

For example, from:

```
data.0001, data.0002, data.0003, data.0004, data.0005, data.0006...
```

to

```
textF_a.fcs, textF_b.fcs, textF_c.fcs, textVv_a.fcs, textVv_b.fcs, textVv_c.fcs ...
```

I tried to do it with [file.rename(from, to)](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/files.html) but failed as the arguments have different lengths (and I don't know what it means):

```
a <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "data.*$")  
b <- paste("data", 1:1180, ".fcs", sep = "")  
file.rename(a, b)
```

Comment: FWIW, the `rename` command in Linux supports Perl-style regular expressions (it was authored by Larry Wall).  Also, the code given would be safer as `seq(a)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, one issue is that your first file isn't named "data.001" - it's named "data.1".  Use this:

```
b <- sprintf("data%.4d.fcs", seq(a))
```

It prepends up to 3 0s (since it seems you have 1000+ files, this may be better) to indices < 1000, so that all names have the same width.  If you really just want to see things like "data.001", then use `%.3d` in the command.

Comment: I think your answer here is the solution to the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865177/problems-with-flowcore-package , not this one ... because it affects the **output** format, not the number of files detected

Comment: @BenBolker I suspect that the file in the other question doesn't exist, because he didn't format things in the way intended.  As for the argument lengths, `seq(a)` should ensure that `b` is the same length as `a`, no?  The OP split the question, but the other question really arises because his expectations for the renaming were possibly incorrect.  For the other question, I asked him to produce `file.info()` output.  If the file really does exist, it's not from the renaming done by the OP or the other answerer.  :)

Comment: @stan glad to help.  Does it mean your other question no longer applies?

Comment: @Iterator: yes, thanks to all who replied to these questions :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code "works" on my machine ("works" in the sense that, when I created a set of files and followed your procedure, the renaming happened correctly). The error is likely that the number of files that you have (`length(a)`) is different from the number of new names that you give (`length(b)`). Post back if it turns out that these objects do have the same length.

Comment: Thank you @Charlie :)! Unfortunately I faced some other problems: when i type `file.rename(a, b)` it returns many FALSEs and after a `library(flowCore')` the function `isFCSfile("data.001")` it returns FALSE again :(... What's wrong...?

Comment: @stan: please open a new question regarding your comment. BTW if you want `b` to be the same length, try: `b <- paste("data", 1:length(a), ".fcs", sep = "")`

Comment: @stan if this answer appears to be correct, consider accepting it (the check at the left should turn green when you click it).

Comment: @stan try giving us a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

As with the (very similar) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758965/how-do-i-rename-files-using-r?lq=1), this function might be of use to you. I wrote it to allow regex find and replace in R. If you're on a mac it can detect and use the frontmost Finder window as a target. Also supports test runs, over-write control, and filtering large folders.

```
umxRenameFile <- function(baseFolder = "Finder", findStr = NA, replaceStr = NA, listPattern = NA, test = T, overwrite = F) {
    # uppercase = u$1
    if(baseFolder == "Finder"){
        baseFolder = system(intern = T, "osascript -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to get the POSIX path of (target of front window as alias)'")
        message("Using front-most Finder window:", baseFolder)
    } else if(baseFolder == "") {
        baseFolder = paste(dirname(file.choose(new = FALSE)), "/", sep = "") ## choose a directory
        message("Using selected folder:", baseFolder)
    }
    if(is.na(listPattern)){
        listPattern = findStr
    }
    a = list.files(baseFolder, pattern = listPattern)
    message("found ", length(a), " possible files")
    changed = 0
    for (fn in a) {
        findB = grepl(pattern = findStr, fn) # returns 1 if found
        if(findB){
            fnew = gsub(findStr, replace = replaceStr, fn) # replace all instances
            if(test){
                message("would change ", fn, " to ", fnew)  
            } else {
                if((!overwrite) & file.exists(paste(baseFolder, fnew, sep = ""))){
                    message("renaming ", fn, "to", fnew, "failed as already exists. To overwrite set T")
                } else {
                    file.rename(paste(baseFolder, fn, sep = ""), paste(baseFolder, fnew, sep = ""))
                    changed = changed + 1;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(test){
                # message(paste("bad file",fn))
            }
        }
    }
    message("changed ", changed)
}
```

Comment: Please check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57836/proper-handling-for-different-question-same-answer