# How to extract a name from a content of a text file?

Tags: r

I have a text file that can be read as:

```
    file=read.table("C:\\data.txt", sep="")
    > class(file)
   [1] "data.frame"
    > head(file)
    name     bat     cat co ro
 1 face     2        16 25  96
```

I have many text files in a directory that can be listed as:

```
   dir<- list.files("C:\\datasets", "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
```

the files are named like this:

```
     ds_ds_df_2011_ 25_96.txt
     this corresponds to:
    ds_ds_df_2011_ co_ro.txt # co ro change while the rest is the same in all files.
```

where `co` is `file$co`  and `ro` is `file$ro`.

What I need is to add the corresponding `name` from `file$name`  to the files names to become:
`ds_ds_df_2011_ co_ro_name.txt`

is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rename files using R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758965/how-do-i-rename-files-using-r)

Comment: Not at all. It has nothing to do with that one.

Comment: Aww, really ? You're not trying to rename files ?

Comment: just to add names extracted from a text file to them?

Comment: What I understood is that you want to rename `ds_ds_df_2011_ 25_96.txt` into `ds_ds_df_2011_ 25_96_face.txt`.

Comment: Yes but this is really different from that question.

Comment: Remove `.txt` from `dir`, append `_co_ro_name`, append `.txt`.

Comment: Not that much, it gives you clues on how to do it, using `file.rename`. You just have to get the subset of you df with the corresponding values ...

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Sorry I did not get you

Comment: It would appear I do not understand part of your question. Can you make it clearer what are your inputs and desired output?

Comment: I want to rename `ds_ds_df_2011_ 25_96.txt` into `ds_ds_df_2011_ 25_96_face.txt` based on `file$name`.

Comment: Read first file `ds_ds_df_2011_ 25_96` , find the name from `file$name` that corresponds to `25` (file$co) and add it to the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seems being too lazy to try by yourself:

```
library(stringr)

sapply(dir,function(x) { 
             val <- str_match(x,"ds_ds_df_2011_ (\\d+)_(\\d+).txt")         
             dest <- paste0( sub(".txt$","",x), "_", df$name[df$co==val[2] & df$ro==val[3]],".txt") 
             file.rename(x,dest)  
           })
```

What's done in the dest line is:

- `sub(".txt","",x)` remove the .txt from the file name
- `df$name[df$co==val[2] & df$ro==val[3]]` Get the name from the data frame where co and ro are the values extracted from the file name just before.
- `paste0(...)` Glue together the start of the file name, an underscore, the name extracted from the df and the .txt extension

I used `df` instead of your original `file`. Generic advice: NEVER use a keyword as a variable name, it lead to problems.

Backup your files before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that uses `match()` to look up the right name in the data frame (here named `df`) and doesn't require any packages. Note, though, that it assumes the order of file names in `dir` matches the row ordering in `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("face", "head"), bat = seq(2), cat = c(16, 26), co = c(25, 35), ro = c(96, 106))
dir <- c("ds_ds_df_2011_ 25_96.txt", "ds_ds_df_2011_ 35_106.txt")

sapply(dir, function(x) {
  sub("\\.", paste0("_", df$name[match(x, dir)], "."), x)
})
```

And here's the output from that:

```
        ds_ds_df_2011_ 25_96.txt        ds_ds_df_2011_ 35_106.txt 
 "ds_ds_df_2011_ 25_96_face.txt" "ds_ds_df_2011_ 35_106_head.txt"
```

Comment: the order thing is a problem because the order of file names in dir DOES matches the row ordering in df.

Comment: If it does match, then this should work. The problem would arise if the order did not match. Have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to say DOES NOT matche the row ordering in df.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably too brittle to be useful. The previous answer is more flexible and therefore better.