# How to change the output filename of a raster time series in R?

Tags: r

I have a large time series (> 2000 files), but as example, I am going to use just a list of 10 tif files:

```
> # list of tif files
> setwd("...raster/daily/")
> l <- list.files(getwd(), pattern=".tif")
```

I get this result:

```
> l
> [1] "ws_1.tif"  "ws_10.tif" "ws_2.tif"  "ws_3.tif"  "ws_4.tif"  "ws_5.tif"  "ws_6.tif"  "ws_7.tif"  "ws_8.tif"  "ws_9.tif
```

I need to change each filemame to something like this:

**new_Year-Month-Day.tif**

new_2009-01-01.tif

new_2009-01-02.tif

new_2009-01-03.tif

...

I am trying to do this with the command below, but without success:

```
# command for to rewrite the set of raster files with the new filenames
for (i in 1:length(l)){
  r <- raster(l[i])
  tempo <- seq(as.Date("2009/01/02"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
  filename = paste0("new_",tempo)
  writeRaster(r, extension(filename, 'tif'))
}
```

When I use this command, the R just create the first file (*new_2009-01-01.tif*) and return the following error:

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
In addition: There were 22 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I already tried to use other commands like **stack** and **brick** the raster files, **names** to set the new names, but still unsuccessful.

Does anyone know how to do this or at least point me another way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758965/how-do-i-rename-files-using-r

Comment: you can use `file.rename(l,filename)` in your code above. You don't need the loop `from(i in 1:length(l))`

Comment: @raninjan, thank you! It worked. So, to solve my problem I used:
`l <- list.files(getwd(), pattern=".tif")
tempo <- seq(as.Date("2009/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
filename = paste0("new_",tempo,".tif")
file.rename(l,filename)`

Comment: that's great! Glad it helped :)