# Rename files and save a log of old and new filenames using R

Tags: r, file-rename, batch-rename

I am trying to remove bias from a microscopy analysis, so I want to make it so the experimenter doesn't know what the conditions are for the image they are looking at.

To do this I need to rename every file in a directory so they can't be identified, but I also need to be able to know what the original filename was subsequently.

I made a folder with three files in it to try this out. I got the file list and made a vector for the new names, and combined into a data frame .

```
setwd("~/Desktop/folder1")
filename_list<-list.files("~/Desktop/folder1")
new_filenames <- c("anon1", "anon2", "anon3")
require(reshape2)
df1 <- melt(data.frame(filename_list,new_filenames))
View(df1)
```

I've also been able to change names using scripts from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758965/how-do-i-rename-files-using-r)
and [r bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/programatically-rename-files-or-do-other-stuff-to-them-in-r/) using sapply and file.rename. I got a little stuck with using wildcards in this to select the whole filename (minus extension) but i'm sure it's possible;

```
sapply(filename_list,FUN=function(eachPath){file.rename(from=eachPath,to=sub(pattern="image_",replacement="anon",eachPath))})
```

How I can get the new_filenames vector and apply it to file.rename so it corresponds to the original_filenames vector in the df1 data frame,
or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.