# Rename files based on a matching value from datafrom in R

Tags: r, file, rename

Suppose I have 3 files named

```
JohnDoe, PeterGynn, JolieHope
```

in a folder and now I would like to change the filename from matching values of a data frame df1.

```
df1 <- structure(list(employee = c("John Doe", "Peter Gynn", "Jolie Hope"), salary = c(21000, 23400, 26800)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

so the final file name would be

```
21000, 23400, 26800
```

Basically, I want to change the file name from the matching employee column to the salary column. I can do it in bash

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "/%P\n" | while read FILE ; do DIR=$(dirname "$FILE" );\
```

but donot know in r

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you had a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758965/how-do-i-rename-files-using-r

Comment: @peter It for adding suffix, prifix or removing some specific character. I want to change the file name from matching row to another column row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just before the operation

```
setwd('~/Desktop/Stack/')

list.files()
```

output :

```
'JohnDoe''JolieHope''PeterGynn'
```

here is how I did;

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(list(employee = c("John Doe", "Peter Gynn", "Jolie Hope"), salary = c(21000, 23400, 26800)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

df1 %>%
mutate(filename=gsub(' ','',employee)) -> df2

for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
    
    old_name <- df2[i]$filename
    new_name <- as.character(df2[i]$salary)
    
    file.rename(from=old_name,to = new_name)

}
```

and this is after

```
list.files()

'21000''23400''26800'
```