# Change name of files in a folder by a specific starting string

Tags: r

I need to change the first part of some files that I have in a directory

```
sdr5569-abc-trix.txt
sdr5569-bcd-trix.txt
sdr5680-abc-trix.txt
sdr5680-bcd-trix.txt
sdr5481-abc-trix.txt
sdr5481-bcd-trix.txt
```

and I need to change the codes with this codes:

```
asx1113-abc-trix.txt
asx1113b-bcd-trix.txt
asx1345-abc-trix.txt
asx1345b-bcd-trix.txt
asx2678-abc-trix.txt
asx2678-bcd-trix.txt
```

the new code asx + numbers are just random generated numbers that I need to change the names of files to be shared, avoiding the to share original codes. It is just an example

I have tried with the solution in this post: [How do I rename files using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758965/how-do-i-rename-files-using-r)
but I could not add the b in the ones with pattern bcd
is there a way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand where the new *numbers*  come from. Could you edit the question with an explanation?

Comment: With `file.rename`, e.g. `vec1 <- c("sdr5569-abc-trix.txt", "sdr5569-bcd-trix.txt", "sdr5680-abc-trix.txt", 
"sdr5680-bcd-trix.txt", "sdr5481-abc-trix.txt", "sdr5481-bcd-trix.txt"
); vec2 <- c("asx1113-abc-trix.txt", "asx1113b-bcd-trix.txt", "asx1345-abc-trix.txt", 
"asx1345b-bcd-trix.txt", "asx2678-abc-trix.txt", "asx2678-bcd-trix.txt"
); file.rename(vec1, vec2)`

Comment: why do you need to add the `b` to `asx1113` if it is already unique with the following `-bcd-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
setwd("Where/your/files/are/stored")
library(dplyr)

file_names <- c("sdr5569-abc-trix.txt", "sdr5569-bcd-trix.txt", "sdr5680-abc-trix.txt",
                "sdr5680-bcd-trix.txt", "sdr5481-abc-trix.txt","sdr5481-bcd-trix.txt")

sdr_names <- gsub("-.*", "", file_names )

set.seed(123)
rnd_vals <- sample(1000:9999, length(unique(sdr_names)))

data.frame(sdr_names, file_names ) %>% 
  mutate(new_names = paste0("asx",
                           rnd_vals[cur_group_id()], 
                           c("", letters[-1])[1:n()],
                           gsub("^.*?(-)", "\\1\\2", file_names)), 
         .by = sdr_names) -> frename_df

frename_df
#>   sdr_names           file_names             new_names
#> 1   sdr5569 sdr5569-abc-trix.txt  asx3462-abc-trix.txt
#> 2   sdr5569 sdr5569-bcd-trix.txt asx3462b-bcd-trix.txt
#> 3   sdr5680 sdr5680-abc-trix.txt  asx3510-abc-trix.txt
#> 4   sdr5680 sdr5680-bcd-trix.txt asx3510b-bcd-trix.txt
#> 5   sdr5481 sdr5481-abc-trix.txt  asx9717-abc-trix.txt
#> 6   sdr5481 sdr5481-bcd-trix.txt asx9717b-bcd-trix.txt
  
file.rename(frename_df$file_names, frename_df$new_names)
```