# File renaming using R

Tags: r, rename

I am trying to rename several files using R, and I have tried every solution I was able to find to similar questions without success.

I have created a vector with the names of the files I want to change, and another one with the names I want to change them to, so they'll look something like:

```
from1 <- as.character(c("test1.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt"))
to1 <- as.character(c("testA.txt", "testB.txt", "testC.txt"))
```

where `from1` corresponds to the names of the existing files in my working directory, and `to1` corresponds to the names I want them to have. When I try `file.rename(from1, to1)` I get `[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE` and even if I try it with just one element of the vector as in `file.rename(from1[1], to1[1])`I just get `[1] FALSE` and nothing happens in my folder

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758965/how-do-i-rename-files-using-r) function posted as an answer to a question very similar to mine, and it seems to work, because when I run a test I get

```
found 1 possible files
would change test1.txt to testA.txt
changed 0
```

but when I actually try to do it I get

```
found 1 possible files
changed 1
```

but nothing has actually changed in my directory.

I am not sure if this question is clear enough or more code is needed, if so please ask and I'll be happy to edit.

Comment: the code works for me.Are you sure that you are in the directory of the files ? Use `getwd()` and `setwd()`

Comment: also, no need for the `as.character` as the `"  "` already defines a character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename files with a specific pattern in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864931/how-to-rename-files-with-a-specific-pattern-in-r)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that you are in the right working directory (otherwise set it with `setwd("")`, you can change file names with:

```
from1 <- c("test_file.csv", "plot1.svg")
to1 <- c("test.csv", "plot.svg")

file.rename(from1, to1)
```

But make sure that you are in the right directory and that the files exist (which you can do with `list.files` or `file.exists`.

Answer (score 1):

To rename a file in R, simply use:

```
file.rename("mytest.R", "mytest2.R")
```

This command can also be vectorized.

```
files.org = c("mytest1.R","mylife.R")
files.new = c("mytest01.R","mytest02.R")
file.rename(files.org, files.new)
```